# cross platform way to explore the containing folder of a file

Tags: java, browser, directory, windows-explorer

is there functionality in java to open the containing folder of a file across any platform. I can accomplish this in windows by running

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("explorer /select,c:\\sampleFile.txt");
```

You can open a file (if the Desktop api is supported) on any platform with `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`. Is there something similar to bring up a file manager?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if you call getDesktop().open(file.getParentFile()) ?

Comment: Works fantastically. Thanks for saving me from more platform specific code.

Comment: cool. Thx. e.g. ```java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop.open(new File("/home/user"))```